# Powershell if statement within pipeline, distingued by date

Tags: powershell, csv, date, datetime, format

I have a csv file full of computer information formatted:

```
Name    OS  Site Code    AD_Status  Region  Tech
computerone Windows 10 Enterprise   ****    Exists  Chicago T T
computertwo Windows 10 Enterprise   ****    Exists  Chicago T T
computerthree   Windows 10 Enterprise   ****    Exists  Chicago T T
```

and I'm running a Powershell script that grabs the computer name and 'modifyTimeStamp' field from the csv file:

```
Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\ttaiw001\Desktop\powershell scripts\testexcel.csv'-Delimiter "," | Select -expand Name | Get-ADComputer -prop modifyTimeStamp | Select Name, ModifyTimeStamp
```

which prints:

```
Name            modifyTimeStamp
----            ---------------
computerone 7/19/2019 11:06:22 AM
computertwo 7/24/2019 6:02:14 AM
computerthree 7/24/2019 2:02:14 AM
```

How can I add an if statement within the pipeline. I need it to function similar to:

```
#if modifyTimeStamp older than 31 days, remove computer name from AD
#something like:

if(Get-modifyTimeStamp).AddDays(-31){
   Remove-ADComputer -Identity "computername"

}
```

But how can implement this if statement in my current powershell script pipeline of:

```
Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\ttaiw001\Desktop\powershell scripts\testexcel.csv'-Delimiter "," | Select -expand Name | Get-ADComputer -prop modifyTimeStamp | Select Name, ModifyTimeStamp
```

Comment: hte `ForEach-Object` cmdlet is designed to allow you to put almost anything in the pipeline. use that to embed your `IF` block.

Comment: Note that both the `modifyTimeStamp` and the `whenChanged` attributes are **not** replicated by default in Active Directory. The modifyTimeStamp is a constructed attribute that is effectively an alias for whenChanged. In order to get the "true" value, you need to query all DCs in the domain and select the most recent value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
#get the date from the previous month (today's date - 1 month)
$lastmonthdate = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

#grabs csv from computer path
Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\***\testexcel.csv'-Delimiter "," |

#from csv file, grabs name of computer and last login time(modify time stamp)
Select-Object -expand Name | Get-ADComputer -prop modifyTimeStamp | Select-Object Name, ModifyTimeStamp | 

#if computer's last login time is older than a month, remove computer from active directory
ForEach-Object { If ($_.ModifyTimeStamp.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -lt $lastmonthdate) { Remove-ADComputer -Identity $_.Name } }
```

Answer (score 0):

In powershell filtering in pipe is made using `Where-Object { expression }`

```
$collection | 
    Where-Object { ( $_.ModifyTimeStamp -gt $value1 ) -or ($_.ModifyTimeStamp -le $value2 ) } | 
    Where-Object { <one more condition> } | 
    Where-Object { <one more condition> } | 
    ...
    Foreach-Object { Do-Something With $_ }
```

In your case:

```
$CheckDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddMonths(-1)
Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\***\testexcel.csv' -Delimiter "," |
    ForEach-Object { 
        try { 
            return Get-ADComputer -Identity $_.Name -Properties @('Name','modifyTimeStamp')
        } catch {
             return $null
        } |
    Where-Object { $_ -ne $null } | 
    Where-Object { $_.ModifyTimeStamp -lt $CheckDate } |
    ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Removing $($_.Name)`t" -NoNewLine
        try {
            Remove-ADComputer -Identity $_ -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host -f 'Green' "OK!"
        } catch {
            Write-Host -f 'Yellow' "Error $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
```

Your mistakes:

1. **F__KING IMPORTANT!** nor `ModifyTimeStamp` nor `WhenChanged` attribute is **NOT REPLICATED ACROSS DCs!** by default. [READ HERE](http://blog.joeware.net/2006/10/03/655/). You have to query ALL DCs in your forest to get real ModifyTimeStamp of your computer. BTW, with `lastlogon` it is the same - it is not replicated as usual.
2. `Select-Object Name, ModifyTimeStamp` - You usually do not need to make object smaller when passing through pipeline. Select removes all properties except you wrote. This can cause problems.
3. No check if computer exists ( `Get-ADComputer` runs OK )
4. Do not compare dates using strings. Compare them as dates ( [DateTime] type )!
5. Do not use `Get-Date` for such tasks usually, because it have current time. Use `[DateTime]::Today`. This gives you 00:00:00 in the morning of current day.